# Sublime Text 2: Is it possible to clear or clean the project-switching dialog cache?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to switch projects frequently. Until recently, I stored all of my `.sublime-project` and `.sublime-workspace` files in my home directory. In a recent cleanup I decided to move them all into a sub-folder of my home directory.

Now, the switch-project dialog shows the cached references to the old location of the project files alongside their new locations. It's a real pain in the rear because I have to compare the paths to make sure I select the correct entry.

Is there any way, short of nuking my install and starting fresh, to clear this cache?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744365/removing-projects-in-sublime-text-2-and-3  - similar Q with several answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the "recent_workspaces" section of session.sublime_session in your settings folder. More details here:

http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/84110-switch-project-dialog-shows-deleted-projects/

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can't make your edits using Sublime. (Guessing, but it seems like it re-saves from memory on quit, so changes are lost.)

Comment: The [Project Management](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Project%20Manager) package helps to avoid this kind of issue by moving your project files to the `Packages/Users/Projects` folder and providing better command palette options for projects.